# Protractor - How to sendKeys to contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I need to test this `contenteditable` `<div>` element. `sendKeys` is not working.

```html
<quill-editor format="html" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted">
  <div quill-editor-element="" class="ql-container ql-snow">
    <div class="ql-editor ql-blank" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Insert text here ...">
      <p style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"><br></p>
    </div>
    <div class="ql-clipboard" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1">
    </div>
  </div>
</quill-editor>
```

I tried the below code but I'm getting below error;

> element not interactable"

```js
element(by.css('.ql-editor')).click();
element(by.css('.ql-editor')).sendKeys('Test');
```

What can I use to enter text in this field?

Comment: could you provide some html context for those elements? maybe you need to locate another element rather

Comment: updated the html. element.click works fine, but sendkey is not working

Comment: Do you need to enter text into p tag after br?

Comment: yes. I can see that when I enter text in this field, it adds it in p tag.

Comment: I also tried the xpath "//div/p" and css ".ql-editor > p" but im getting the same element not interactable error

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

1. Check if after clicking the element it's ID changes or not
2. Wait for few seconds and then try to send the keys.